# object 'count' not found when using bymedian sorting method in R?

Tags: r, sorting, boxplot

I'm pretty new to R so this is probably a simple question for the community.

I have a .csv file with 10 variables and 79 observations. I can plot a box plot of the `Vcmax` data grouped by `treatment` but when I try to organise the box plot by median (either ascending or descending) I hit a snag.

I use this code:

```
library(graphics)
bymedian <- with(Results2, reorder(Vcmax, -count, median))
boxplot(Vcmax ~ treatment, data=Results2, ylim=c(70,300), axes=TRUE, cex.axis=0.4,         
xlab = "Species", ylab = "Vcmax",         
main = "Species-Specific Variation in Vcmax", varwidth = TRUE,
          col = "lightgray")
```

However R returns the error message:

> Error in tapply(X = X, INDEX = x, FUN = FUN, ...) :    object 'count'
>   not found

Is there something else i need to do to my data to help R recognise which data to sort and how to sort it? I'm sure it is something obvious...

It produces a really nice graph but not sorted.

Here is (hopefully) a link where you can download the data: http://expirebox.com/download/4258dc66916cdc054486f4f1bb7cfb55.html